# number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: pdo

I am facing "**number of bound variables does not match number of tokens**" exception while trying to use multiple condition in where clause using PDO.

code:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";
$dbname = "yyyy";

$searchParam = $_POST['typeahead']; 
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM trucks WHERE plate_number LIKE :plateNumber OR company_name LIKE: companyName");
    $stmt->bindValue(':plateNumber', '%'.$searchParam.'%', PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':companyName', '%'.$searchParam.'%', PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

I am trying to search depending on either `plate_number` or `company_name`. For the same reason I am binding the two place holders(variables). the code works while I use only 1 variable but not two. how to bind two variables?

Comment: there is an extra space in the query. This question should be deleted

Answer (score -2):

You can use

```
$stmt->bindValue(array(':plateNumber', '%'.$searchParam.'%', PDO::PARAM_INT,':companyName', '%'.$searchParam.'%', PDO::PARAM_INT));
```